# i have create new sql server database option unable on visual studio express for web

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have installed visual studio express 2012 for web but "create new SQL server database" option is unable on data connections. what version of SQL server do I need to make this option enable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the SQL Server Express, which is free:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29062